# Append string to activity's android:label

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is it possible to append a string to an activity's android:label attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml file, if I'm using a value from the string.xml file?  I'd like to append my app's name to each activity's title/label, ie:

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity1" android:label="@string/app_name + "-" + Main Activity">
```

So the title/label of the activity would display as:

App Name - Main Activity

and another would be:

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity2" android:label="@string/app_name + "-" + Another Activity">
```

Which would display as:

App Name - Another Activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You will have to create those strings manually in your strings.xml file. You can't concatenate those strings in the strings.xml file either.

Comment: You could also create them on the fly in your activites onCreate if the names are data dependent.

Comment: Any idea how to create them on the fly?

Comment: In the `Activity` there is a method called `setTitle`; just build and pass it the string you want to show in the title.